# aria-labelledby not being read by NVDA Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, accessibility

When user uses screen reader, I want H2 element to be read out from hidden text stored in span element. This does not work with NVDA and Chrome/FF browsers. When I roll over the h2 element, it just reads "This is header" instead of "This is Test"

```
<div >    
    <span id="hdnlbl" class="visuallyhidden">This is Test</span>
    <h2 aria-labelledby="hdnlbl">This is header</h2>
</div>
```

here is live example https://jsfiddle.net/pwzeus/8jb1mxdm/13/

**EDIT**

Requirement is that it has to work on mouse over. How do I make that work ?

Comment: This is working for me when I arrow key through elements

Comment: If it works on arrow keys that's all that's needed. Very few screenreader users can use a mouse.

Comment: For me, it reads "Heading Level 2, This is Test."
Using NVDA 2017.3, Chrome v62, on Windows 10.

Comment: Interesting , I am also on v62 and win 10. I am trying this with mouse over but you are right, this should be only tested for key board

Comment: Actually the requirement is that it has to work on mouse rollover

Comment: Sight impaired people usually use the tab key and arrow keys over a mouse.

Answer (score 0):

by the class I understood that your `span` is hidden-`aria-labelledby` will be read only when the element(the span in the example) isn't hidden
(we use it for errors when the error is hidden the error isn't read for the input and when the error is visible it will be read for the input)
good luck
shelli
accessibility expert